# Flutter Html View Returns Error When Imported

Tags: flutter, dart

I have successfully installed the dependency in pubspec.yaml and the exit code was 0.
When I `import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';` It shows that it has been imported via vs code (It underlines it as imported but not used)**

But when I save or restart my emulator, it will refuse to build. returning the following errors:

`/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_markdown-0.2.0/lib/src/builder.dart:326:49: Error: The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'InlineSpan'.`

````
 - 'InlineSpan' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/inline_span.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/inline_span.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'children'.
        List<TextSpan> children = previous.text.children != null
                                                ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_markdown-0.2.0/lib/src/builder.dart:327:41: Error: The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'InlineSpan'.

 - 'InlineSpan' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/inline_span.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/inline_span.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'children'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'children'.
          ? new List.from(previous.text.children)
                                        ^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_markdown-0.2.0/lib/src/builder.dart:326:49: Error: The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'InlineSpan'.
 - 'InlineSpan' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/inline_span.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/inline_span.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'children'.
        List<TextSpan> children = previous.text.children != null
                                                ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_markdown-0.2.0/lib/src/builder.dart:327:41: Error: The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'InlineSpan'.
 - 'InlineSpan' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/inline_span.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/inline_span.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'children'.

          ? new List.from(previous.text.children)
                                        ^^^^^^^^```
````

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` and building again?

Answer (score 1):

What are your SDK constraints? You're using an extremely old version (`0.2.0`) of `package:flutter_markdown` from 2018, back from before Flutter was even stable. Using the [latest compatible version](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown/versions) (`^0.6.2`, ideally) should fix your issue.

Comment: Flutter_html_view has not been updated since August 2019 as well. I ended up ditching it which made upgrading all of the other packages easier and led to a successful compilation. I also forced CocoaPods to use later versions by a section of script at the bottom of the Pods file. Flutter does not respect the version request of the CocoaPods in the Pods file. It seems you have to force it.